# Enable exporting of billing data for google cloud to BigQuery using APIs

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to enable export billing data to BigQuery/storage   datasets/buckets using APIs if billing export is not enabled, i.e. what I need to do is

1. Check if billing export is enabled.
2. **If not:**
        Enable billing exports and export data to the preferred dataset/bucket with some name.
   **If yes:**
        Get the name of the dataset/bucket which is being used for billing exports.
3. Above steps need to be performed with the help of APIs and I am using python to integrate it.

Comment: GCP Support here. I've poked around some and it's not possible today, but it is being tracked as a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70525274